# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Equivalent in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, dispatcher

I'm struggling with using the dispatcher with caliburn.micro in wpf. My codes in xaml.cs goes like this.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, new Action(() =>
             {
                //function here.

             }));
```

Is there any way I can use the dispatcher in my viewmodel or any equivalent for caliburn.micro? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need that. You should update your viewModel's properties and use `NotifyOfPropertyChange();`

Comment: You can access the main UI thread's Dispatcher by `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.